# Cache manifest on ipad

Tags: ipad, html, mobile-safari, manifest, application-cache

I have a ipad. I make a website with html5 application storage. With a manifest file. The manifest is working on the new ipad 2 and all the web browsers. But it is not working on the ipad 2 with a lower ios version.

The problem is. When i loaded the page. The manifest file is caching the website. I turn airplane mode on. Now i can used the website without a internet connection.

But the problem is. When i now reloading the page. I get a error, that i need a internet connection to view the page. How can i fix this. This problem is in safari.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working through similar issue. 
I have an iPad 1 so not exactly the same platform, and I know this sounds a bit "did you turn it off and on again" but you need to make completely sure there are absolutely NO errors in your cache manifest. If you are using a file in your app that is not listed in the cache manifest file, your app will try and function without the missing file. This is particularly relevant when using multiple js files. Anything missing (an easy thing to do when you are in rapid development) will crash your app offline.

Comment: Have a look at your website in chrome. Its developer tools console shows application cache progress events. It will flag up any errors it comes across too.